# Paperclip with S3 requires PutObjectAcl

Tags: amazon-s3, paperclip, policy

In setting up S3 with paperclip, I thought this action for an IAM policy sounded reasonable:

`"Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
            ]`

But this resulted in a 403 error.

I read on another question to add `s3:PutObjectAcl`, like this:

`"Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ]`

And that worked.

Why do I need to ability to adjust the Acl? I am using paperclip and the `aws-sdk` gem. I would think paperclip would just upload the image and be done and leave the acl to the bucket?